# div centering techniques / question

Tags: html, css

I've got a div with a background color blue, that needs to be centered in another div with background green -- just for looks.  I centered the blue div inside the green div with a "margin: 10px auto".  Now, I need the text inside this blue div to be left justified, not centered, so I put the text inside a div and gave it a margin of zero. That didn't work.

Obviously I'm confused about centering things in general, and am still coming up the css centering / positioning learning curve.  Any thoughts / comments appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place a:

```
text-align: left
```

style on the DIV containing the text.

margin: auto only works for centering DIVS, has no effect on actual text